# Does every Spin$(7)$-manifold has a unit-length spinor?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry, holonomy, spinor

Say $M$ be a manifold with a Spin$(7)$-structure. $M$ is spin and hence spin$^c$. Say $S=S_+\oplus S_-$ be a spin$^c$-bundle on $M$. Does $S_+$ has a nowhere vanishing section? The result is true if it was a spin-bundle.